# No module named '_cffi_backend' cx_freeze

Tags: python, cx-freeze

This is my probleme: I want to build an application with cx_freeze, my setup.py file is like this:

```
import os, sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

path = sys.path
base = "Win32GUI"
includes = ["paramiko"]

cible_1 = Executable(
    script = "UIpreparFact.py",
    base = base,
    )

options = {"path": path,
             "includes": includes,
             "packages": ['os', 'cffi', 'idna']
           }

setup(
    name = "PreparFact",
    version = "1.0",
    description = "Triage selon code",
    author = "Tsifi",
    options = {"prepareFact_exe": options},
    executables = [cible_1]
    )
```

I launch `python setup.py build`  this commande run without error and I have build directory, when I launch my app.exe, I have this error:
[cx_freeze build error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaOJX.png)

Someone can help me to solve this probleme?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have the same error... did you solve it?

Comment: yes the solution I used is using installing python on the OS but not using WinPy. :)

Comment: Can you post your setup.py? I have a problem with paramiko, it works on my machine but it doesn't when I try on another machine...